# MongoDB without first element

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I'm inserting documents (Persons) into a MongoDB collection with Java. I get the following JSON example:

```
{"Person": {
  "Name": "",
  "Firstname": ""
}}
```

When I put that into may Person collection, then I also have the _id and then the Person with its sub-elements. But I would like to add only the child attributes (Name, Firstname) to the collection, beacause the collection is already called "Person" *(Patient in the screenshot of MongoVUE)*.

[image]

**Question 1**: What is the best practice when putting such JSON to the DB, is the parent element important should be inserted to the database, or should only the sub-elements be inserted?

**Question 2**: My Java code looks like this, if I only want to add the sub-elements to the MongoDB, how can I do that? Because I would then have to insert a collection of elements...

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("MyDB");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("Person");

BasicDBObject patientMongo = (BasicDBObject) JSON.parse("{"Person": {"Name": "", "Firstname": ""}}");
collection.insert(patientMongo);
```

Comment: What is the exact schema you expect? `Person:{Name:"n", Firstname:"fn"}` or `Persons:[{Name:"n", Firstname:"fn"}, {Name:"n2", Firstname:"fn2"}]`?

Comment: I expect in the mongoVue the content without person root element: {_id:"...",Name:"n", etc...

Answer (score 0):

This would help, I think.

```
BasicDBObject patientMongo = (BasicDBObject) JSON.parse("{"Person": {"Name": "", "Firstname": ""}}");

collection.insert((BasicDBObject) patientMongo.get("Person"));
```